polars, combining sales and purchases, FIFO method
I have two dataframes:
One with buys
df_buy = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "BuyId": [1, 2],
        "Item": ["A", "A"],
        "BuyDate": [date.fromisoformat("2023-01-01"), date.fromisoformat("2024-03-07")],
        "Quantity": [40, 50],
    }
)




BuyId
Item
BuyDate
Quantity




1
A
2023-01-01
40


2
A
2024-03-07
50



And other with sells:
df_sell = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "SellId": [3, 4],
        "Item": ["A", "A"],
        "SellDate": [date.fromisoformat("2024-04-01"), date.fromisoformat("2024-05-01")],
        "Quantity": [10, 45],
    }
)





SellId
Item
SellDate
Quantity




3
A
2024-04-01
10


4
A
2024-05-01
45



I want to determine which sales came from which purchases using the FIFO method.
The result should be something like this.



BuyId
Item
BuyDate
RemainingQuantity
SellId
SellDate
SellQuantity
QuantityAfterSell




1
A
2023-01-01
40
3
2024-04-01
10
30


1
A
2023-01-01
30
4
2024-05-01
30
0


2
A
2024-03-07
50
4
2024-05-01
15
35



I know that I can do it using a for loop but I wanted to know if there is a more vectorized way to do it.
Edit:
Added new example for testing:
df_buy = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "BuyId": [5, 1, 2],
        "Item": ["B", "A", "A"],
        "BuyDate": [date.fromisoformat("2023-01-01"), date.fromisoformat("2023-01-01"), date.fromisoformat("2024-03-07")],
        "Quantity": [10, 40, 50],
    }
)

df_sell = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "SellId": [6, 3, 4],
        "Item": ["B", "A", "A"],
        "SellDate": [
            date.fromisoformat("2024-04-01"),
            date.fromisoformat("2024-04-01"),
            date.fromisoformat("2024-05-01"),
        ],
        "Quantity": [5, 10, 45],
    }
)


Not easily, no.  This is a "journal" operation that really needs line-by-line processing.


Calculate total quantity bought so far and total quantity sold so far.


cum_sum() to calculate running total.

df_buy_total = (
    df_buy
    .with_columns(QuantityTotal = pl.col.Quantity.cum_sum().over("Item"))
)

df_sell_total = (
    df_sell
    .with_columns(QuantityTotal = pl.col.Quantity.cum_sum().over("Item"))
)

┌───────┬──────┬────────────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│ BuyId ┆ Item ┆ BuyDate    ┆ Quantity ┆ QuantityTotal │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---           │
│ i64   ┆ str  ┆ date       ┆ i64      ┆ i64           │
╞═══════╪══════╪════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 40       ┆ 40            │
│ 2     ┆ A    ┆ 2024-03-07 ┆ 50       ┆ 90            │
└───────┴──────┴────────────┴──────────┴───────────────┘

┌────────┬──────┬────────────┬──────────┬───────────────┐
│ SellId ┆ Item ┆ SellDate   ┆ Quantity ┆ QuantityTotal │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---           │
│ i64    ┆ str  ┆ date       ┆ i64      ┆ i64           │
╞════════╪══════╪════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════╡
│ 3      ┆ A    ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 10       ┆ 10            │
│ 4      ┆ A    ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 45       ┆ 55            │
└────────┴──────┴────────────┴──────────┴───────────────┘


Find which BuyId and SellId belong together. For this we can use join_asof()

df_sell2buy = (
    df_sell_total
    .join_asof(
        df_buy_total, on="QuantityTotal", strategy="forward", by="Item", coalesce=False, suffix="Buy"
    )
    .select(
        "BuyId", "SellId", "Item", "BuyDate", "SellDate",
        "QuantityTotalBuy",
        pl.col.QuantityTotal.alias("QuantityTotalSell")
    )
    .filter(pl.col.BuyId.is_not_null(), pl.col.QuantityTotalBuy > pl.col.QuantityTotalSell)
)

df_buy2sell = (
    df_buy_total
    .join_asof(
        df_sell_total, on="QuantityTotal", strategy="forward", by="Item", coalesce=False, suffix="Sell"
    )
    .select(
        "BuyId", "SellId", "Item", "BuyDate", "SellDate",
        pl.col.QuantityTotal.alias("QuantityTotalBuy"),
        pl.col.QuantityTotalSell.forward_fill().over("Item").fill_null(0)
    )
)

┌───────┬────────┬──────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ BuyId ┆ SellId ┆ Item ┆ BuyDate    ┆ SellDate   ┆ QuantityTotalBuy ┆ QuantityTotalSell │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---              ┆ ---               │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ str  ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64              ┆ i64               │
╞═══════╪════════╪══════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 3      ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 40               ┆ 10                │
│ 2     ┆ 4      ┆ A    ┆ 2024-03-07 ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 90               ┆ 55                │
└───────┴────────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘

┌───────┬────────┬──────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ BuyId ┆ SellId ┆ Item ┆ BuyDate    ┆ SellDate   ┆ QuantityTotalBuy ┆ QuantityTotalSell │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---              ┆ ---               │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ str  ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64              ┆ i64               │
╞═══════╪════════╪══════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 4      ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 40               ┆ 55                │
│ 2     ┆ null   ┆ A    ┆ 2024-03-07 ┆ null       ┆ 90               ┆ 55                │
└───────┴────────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘


Combine both linked DataFrames

df_result = (
    pl.concat([df_sell2buy, df_buy2sell])
    .filter(~(
        pl.col.SellId.is_null() &
        pl.col.SellId.is_not_null().any().over("BuyId")
    ))
    .sort("Item", "BuyId", "SellId", nulls_last=True)
)

┌───────┬────────┬──────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ BuyId ┆ SellId ┆ Item ┆ BuyDate    ┆ SellDate   ┆ QuantityTotalBuy ┆ QuantityTotalSell │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---              ┆ ---               │
│ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ str  ┆ date       ┆ date       ┆ i64              ┆ i64               │
╞═══════╪════════╪══════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ 3      ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 40               ┆ 10                │
│ 1     ┆ 4      ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 40               ┆ 55                │
│ 2     ┆ 4      ┆ A    ┆ 2024-03-07 ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 90               ┆ 55                │
└───────┴────────┴──────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────────┴───────────────────┘


Calculate final results

(
    df_result
    .with_columns(
        QuantityRunning = pl.min_horizontal("QuantityTotalBuy", "QuantityTotalSell"),
    )    
    .with_columns(
        QuantityRunningPrev = pl.col.QuantityRunning.shift(1).over("Item").fill_null(0)
    )
    .select(
        "BuyId", "Item", "BuyDate",
        (pl.col.QuantityTotalBuy - pl.col.QuantityRunningPrev).alias("RemainingQuantity"),
        "SellId", "SellDate", 
        (pl.col.QuantityRunning - pl.col.QuantityRunningPrev).alias("SellQuantity"),
        (pl.col.QuantityTotalBuy - pl.col.QuantityRunning).alias("QuantityAfterSell")
    )
)

┌───────┬──────┬────────────┬───────────────────┬────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ BuyId ┆ Item ┆ BuyDate    ┆ RemainingQuantity ┆ SellId ┆ SellDate   ┆ SellQuantity ┆ QuantityAfterSell │
│ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---        ┆ ---               ┆ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---          ┆ ---               │
│ i64   ┆ str  ┆ date       ┆ i64               ┆ i64    ┆ date       ┆ i64          ┆ i64               │
╞═══════╪══════╪════════════╪═══════════════════╪════════╪════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 40                ┆ 3      ┆ 2024-04-01 ┆ 10           ┆ 30                │
│ 1     ┆ A    ┆ 2023-01-01 ┆ 30                ┆ 4      ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 30           ┆ 0                 │
│ 2     ┆ A    ┆ 2024-03-07 ┆ 50                ┆ 4      ┆ 2024-05-01 ┆ 15           ┆ 35                │
└───────┴──────┴────────────┴───────────────────┴────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────────┘


Thanks Roman.
I tried puting other Item "B" in the inventory with a buy and no sells  and the buy dissapears.
Also If I tried putting a buy and a sell of the item "B" and the quantities started to get mixed between items.
How can I fix it?

@rlartiga please see updated version

@rlartiga yes, haven't updated the code, now it should be better

It worked!! Thanks!

I'm sorry the late follow up, can you explain me please the sense of df_buy2sell and df_sell2buy?
Also the reason for this:
~(pl.col.SellId.is_null() &     pl.col.SellId.is_not_null().any().over("BuyId")   )

tbh I don't understand why works

@rlartiga I'll try to write down the reasoning this weekend when I have time

thanks, it would be very helpful to me.

Hi @roman I hope you're doing well! I just wanted to kindly follow up on the clarification I requested earlier. I understand you mentioned you’d look into it over the weekend, but I realize you may have been busy. Whenever you have a moment, I'd really appreciate your comments on the methodology of your answer.
Thanks for your time.

@rlartiga sorry didn't find time to get back to it earlier. It requires me to upload the whole context in my head :) I'll try not to forget about it
